# PHP: Is square bracket necessary when setting a variable to an array returned by an WordPress function?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to check if a value is present in the array of selected checkboxes returned from WordPress as in the code below. Is square bracket necessary when setting a variable to an array returned by an WordPress function? If I'm right, square brackets are necessary when one keeps adding elements to an array. In my case, I won't have to add any more element as it is a one time fetch. Please enlighten me on this.

```
<?php
$hide_footer_signup_form[] = get_field('hide_footer_signup_form');
if (in_array('Hide Add to Purpose Form', $hide_footer_signup_form)) { ?>
  #footer-form {
      display: none;
  }
<?php 
} 
?>
```

This doubt came because of the VS Code editor showing the error message.

[image]

Comment: If the value isn't an array, then have you tried `if ('Hide Add to Purpose Form' == $hide_footer_signup_form) {` instead?

Comment: $hide_footer_signup_form is an array although it holds only one element. In get_field('hide_footer_signup_form');, hide_footer_signup_form is the name of a checkbox.

Comment: since $hide_footer_signup_form is an array and get_field() returns a string, the types do not match. although $hide...form = get_field() will work because PHP will automatically change $hide...form to string, it's not a good practice to do so. You can add the data to the array like you do, which is totally fine. Or you can assign the data to a new variable like $field = get_field()

Comment: @AnuratChapanond I chose to do typecasting like `$hide_footer_signup_form = (array) get_field('hide_footer_signup_form');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecasting the returned value as below fixed the issue.

```
$hide_footer_signup_form = (array) get_field('hide_footer_signup_form');
```